# Customize x axis

Tags: plotting

I wanna have x-axis to be like -10^2,-10^1,10^1,10^2. I usually use the table below but I don't know how to modify the code to show the negative side of the x-axis as well

```
 Needs["MaTeX`"]
    SetOptions[MaTeX, 
      "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,braket}"}];
    x-axis = Table[{10^i, 
        MaTeX["10^" <> ToString[i], Magnification -> 1.5]}, {i, 3}];
    Plot[1 + z^2, {z, -100, 100}, 
     FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {x-axis, Automatic}}, 
     Frame -> True,
     FrameStyle -> Black,
     BaseStyle -> 14]
```

[image]

Comment: change `{i, 3}` to `{i,-2, 2}`?

Comment: @kglr no it is not what I want. It gives you, for example, 1o^-2  not -10^2.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]
SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,braket}"}];

range = DeleteCases[Range[-2, 2], 0];
set[i_] := {Sign[i]*10^Abs@i, 
  MaTeX[ If[i < 0, "-10^", "10^"] <> ToString[Abs@i], Magnification -> 1]}

xaxis = Table[set[i], {i, range}];

Plot[1 + z^2, {z, -100, 100}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {xaxis, Automatic}}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, BaseStyle -> 14]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works